# Tree growing as user scrolls

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have an idea for a site with a tree that grows as the user scrolls down the page with branches coming out as it gets bigger. The idea being that the branches will be clickable and show content in a modal, new content will continually be added so the bottom of the tree will have to accommodate this. I was thinking of having it scroll off screen, and as it continues to grow more branches for content will appear.

I'm a PHP developer so am looking for advice on the best way to do this? My current thought is to use JavaScript & Canvas?

I realise it'll take a while for me to learn what I need to for this project but I that's partly the reason I want to develop it.

Comment: Why do it as you scroll, and not time based?

Comment: @ajaxGuru I've updated the question to be more clear. It's basically to do with the branches containing content which will continuously be added over a period of time.

Comment: You're doing time adding now, not scrolling?  Use set interval.

Comment: @ajaxGuru Sorry, it appears that my attempt to make the question clear didn't work. It's still scroll based, the tree grows as the user scrolls. Over time new content will be added but this will be a manual process and allow the user to scroll further to reveal the new  content.

Answer (score 1):

that's possible with Scrollmagic (http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/simple_tweening.html), works well for me...

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll take a look and try it out.